# Retrieving records from database where some values of a particular field are NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a table advisor in which there are columns like AdvisorName, UserName, OrderedOn, ReviewedOn etc.

I want to retrieve those records where the Advisor Name is Julianne Frank and year of OpenedOn is less than 2022 and those records where the values of ReviewedOn are NULL.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Advisor
WHERE AdvisorName = 'Julianne' AND AdvisorLName = 'Franke' AND YEAR(OpenedOn) < 2022 AND ReviewedOn IS NULL;
```

There are records where all these conditions are being met. However, no record is returned. The output is blank (only displaying the column names).

Comment: there won't be any records for which AdvisorName has 2 different values like:  AdvisorName = 'Julianne' AND AdvisorLName = 'Franke'. It will have either name A or name B. 
Are you looking for ( AdvisorName = 'Julianne' OR AdvisorLName = 'Franke')  (inluding the ( )

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a name who is Julianne **AND** Franke

```
AdvisorName = 'Julianne' AND AdvisorLName = 'Franke'
```

You should do that :

```
SELECT *
FROM Advisor
WHERE (AdvisorName = 'Julianne' OR AdvisorLName = 'Franke') AND YEAR(OpenedOn) < 2022 AND ReviewedOn IS NULL;
```

Comment: No this didn't work. 
Besides, why should it work?
You can think of these two columns as FirstName and LastName... 
So, those names whose advisor has first name "Julianne" AND whose last name is "Franke".

Comment: I didn't see the Advisor"L"Name , it should work, your query is correct actually, can you give us a data sample ?